# Codename One change app language in emulator

Tags: codenameone

I want my app to be in different languages. I want to use the localization feature in de resource file.

But I want to test if the language is being changed in different countries. How can I test the different languages? Or do I need to do something via code before showing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator will use the locale from Java SE to simulate that. You can customize the OS locale which Java SE will pick up.

You can customize this via the command line as explained here: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html

In the run section in the IDE preferences just add the JVM args: `-Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=CA`

Comment: Thanks! Another question... What if I want an option where users can select a language. How do I change the language manually via code with this localization option?

Comment: That was answered by @kaya below

Comment: Where do I find this "run section" in Intellij?

Comment: I don't think it's available there since we implemented the IDE support in IntelliJ very differently. There is a section in the intellij XML that includes Java arguments but I'm not sure if it is picked up by the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I think to change programatically, this should be called in the source code

> Hashtable h = res.getL10N("Localization", "de");
>   UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(h);